# Filter items with an email body that contains a less than symbol `<`

Tags: regex, vba, email, outlook

I'm trying to filter items with an email body that contains a less than symbol **`<`**.

Here is a sample email body that contains less than symbol.

> Our drive E: is now < 10%.

```
Sub CodeSubjectForward(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

    Dim M1 As MatchCollection
    Dim M As Match

    Set Reg1 = New RegExp

    With Reg1
        .Pattern = "([<]\s*(\w*)\s*)"
        .Global = True
    End With
    If Reg1.Test(Item.Body) Then

        Set M1 = Reg1.Execute(Item.Body)
        For Each M In M1


        Next
    End If
    Item.Save

    Set myForward = Item.Forward
    myForward.Recipients.Add "alias@domain.com"

    myForward.Send

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the desired behavior? What kind of errors do you get?

Comment: Hello @kelin,

There is no error on the code. Here is the behavior I want, if the email body contains less than symbol <, it will forward to a particular mailbox.

Hope you can help me on this.

Thank you,

Comment: Can you post example of the body?

Comment: Hello @0m3r, here is a sample email body that contains less than symbol.

Our drive E: is now < 10%.

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

*Should be something like this*

```
Public Sub FWItem(Item As Outlook.mailitem)
    Dim Email As Outlook.mailitem
    Dim Matches As Variant
    Dim RegExp As Object
    Dim Pattern As String

    Set RegExp = CreateObject("VbScript.RegExp")

    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.mailitem Then

        Pattern = "(\s[<]\s)"
        With RegExp
            .Global = False
            .Pattern = Pattern
            .IgnoreCase = True
             Set Matches = .Execute(Item.Body)
        End With

        If Matches.Count > 0 Then
            Debug.Print Item.subject ' Print on Immediate Window
            Set Email = Item.Forward
                Email.subject = Item.subject
                Email.Recipients.Add "0m3r@Email.com"
                Email.Save
                Email.Send

        End If
    End If

    Set RegExp = Nothing
    Set Matches = Nothing
    Set Email = Nothing
    Set Item = Nothing
End Sub
```

> ***https://regex101.com/r/KOFM8E/1/***
>
> [image]

Comment: Will try this and keep you posted. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @0m3r, I tried your suggested code above but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @IamBayMax what Outlook version are you running?

Comment: Hello @0m3r, i am using Outlook 2016. Thank you.

Comment: @IamBayMax code works okay on 2010, try deleting your rule and recreate it, see if that helps

Comment: i tried what you have suggested but still, it didn't do anything.

Comment: yes it is. I enabled the Macro Settings in the Trust Center.

Comment: @IamBayMax do you know how to test this code without outlook rule?

Comment: i am not sure. can you please guide me?

Comment: i tried your script in Outlook 2010 but it was still forwarding the emails even though the body did not contains any < on it. 

Here is my sample text

Another test for special characters.

!@#$%^&*()_+=-0987654321{}[]|\”’:;.>,/?`~

Comment: Hello All,

I need you help here to make this work. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you,